# Shape names in ggvis

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

In ggvis properties can be assigned to shapes as

```
mtcars %>% 
    ggvis(~wt,~mpg, shape= ~factor(cyl)) %>%
    layer_points()
```

[image]

I am not sure how to set the scales however. I believe it's supposed to be using `scale_nominal`. But I failed to make it work so far.

I can change the order of things

```
mtcars  %>% 
    ggvis(~wt,~mpg, shape= ~factor(cyl)) %>%
    layer_points()  %>% scale_nominal('shape',c(8,6,4))
```

[image]

But I can't force them to be a shape I want.

In ggplot I would to this by using `scale_shape_manual`

```
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = wt,y = mpg, shape= factor(cyl))) +
    geom_point() + 
    scale_shape_manual(values = c('4' = 15, '6' = 18, '8' = 3))
```

[image]

Note that if I remove all 4s, other shapes are preserved

```
mtcars %>% 
    filter(cyl!=4) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = wt,y = mpg, shape= factor(cyl))) +
        geom_point() + 
        scale_shape_manual(values = c('4' = 15, '6' = 18, '8' = 3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike ggplot's `scale_{whatever}_manual` you cannot set the range of values in a single variable. in `scale_nominal` `domain` and `range` variables control these properties.

```
mtcars  %>% 
    ggvis(~wt,~mpg, shape= ~factor(cyl)) %>%
    layer_points()  %>% 
    scale_nominal('shape',domain = c(4,6,8),range = c('square','cross','diamond'))
```

[image]

Note that ggvis allows a limited palette of shapes: circle (default), square, cross, diamond, triangle-up, or triangle-down